# O365 search managed property mapping issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-property, refiner, crawled-property

I have an issue with mapping managed property to existing crawled property. I am pretty confident in search configuration but this just seems not to work on O365 (working on-prem).

I want to create a refiner which will aggregate values from ows_created_x0020_by and ows_modified_x0020_by

So my steps are:

1. Find managed property RefinableString05
2. Go to mapping -> Add mapping
3. Add ows_created_x0020_by and ows_modified_x0020_by
4. Click ok, I am redirected to managed properties list, I search again for RefinableString05 and this is what I get

[image]

So the mapping is missing - as well in the RefinableString05 detail. I have tried to add mapping for example to Author and it works! Also the mapping for my custom crawled properties works.

Because it is not strange enough already, here is the screenshot from Crawled properties for the ows_created_0x0020_by [image]

As I mentioned, it was tested by my friend on the on-prem farm and it works there. I have successfully created my own crawled properties (based on property bag) and mapped RefinableString00-04 to them. But for some reason I am unable to do this for the 'created by' and 'modified by'.

Why I need this? I want one refiner to filter the documents by the user who has created or modified the document.

Any ideas? Thank you.